# Is there a formula for calculating the difference in minutes or hours between two times?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

Is there a formula for Is there a formula for calculating the difference in minutes or hours between two times in two columns?

In my spreadsheet I have the following two columns called start time and end time. In those fields I enter the time in hours and minutes:

[image]

```
start   end
6:45    7:45
```

I'd like a third column that has the total difference between them like so:

[image]

Is there a formula that will do this? This is for Google Sheets but IIUC formulas from Excel may work in Google sheets???

**UPDATE:**
Using the formula suggested, `=(B1-C1)`, it's giving me the correct hours and minutes (*edit - actually it does work see update 2*).

[image]

Using the other suggestion, `=(B1-C1)*24`, I'm not getting the following value:

[image]

In the second case, if I change the time field to a number it changes:

Before (formatted as automatic):
[image]

After (formatted as Number):
[image]

Here's the menu items:
[image]

**UPDATE 2:**
The formula does work. To get it to work I needed to format the formula cell as a number, not the time cells.

Comment: Be careful of daylight savings time changes, unless the formula is "smart" enough to take that into account, on a region-by-region basis. There's a good reason astronomers use Julian date: https://scienceworld.wolfram.com/astronomy/JulianDate.html

Comment: It generally '[just works](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-or-subtract-time-16aa6697-6d6e-49c1-8e2c-3398a7cad6ad)' - `c2 = b2 - a2`

Comment: Otherwise convert the time/date to Unix time and again the maths is pretty straight forward. 

It looks like you don't have date so that might not help.

Comment: @Insanemal thanks. i noticed when selecting some of the cells that Google Sheets auto detected or inferred that I was entering time information. i tested it and when I put AM or PM in the field or when I use a colon between the numbers but if it's more stable i'll select the time field for this column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method:

1. Format cells to **Number**
   [image]
2. Enter the formula:

   =(B1-A1)*24

[image]

Comment: That works!!! :)

Comment: The formula executes on cells b1 and a1. Is it possible to make it apply to all the rows? So column C executes the function on the current row of column B and A?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1755306/how-to-use-a-specific-formula-in-every-row-in-a-specific-column-now-and-in-the-f

Comment: array formula: ctrl+shift+enter